# Iterate cols PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a SQL table containing 40 columns: ID, Product, Product_ID, Date etc. and would like to iterate over all columns to get distinct values.

`Customer` table (sample):

```
ID Product 
1  gadget
2  VR
2  AR
3  hi-fi
```

I have tried using `dropDuplicates` within a function that loops over all columns but the resultant output is only spitting out one distinct value per column instead of all possible distinct values.

Expected Result:

```
Column    Value
ID        1 
ID        2
ID        3
Product   gadget
Product   VR
Product   AR
Product   hi-fi
```

Actual Result:

```
Column    Value
ID        1 
Product   gadget
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to use [collect_set()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_set) to fetch distinct elements in a column and then `exploding` the dataframe.

```
#All columns which need to be aggregated should be added here in col_list.
col_list = ['ID','Product']
exprs = [collect_set(x) for x in col_list]
```

Let's start aggregating.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit , collect_set, explode, array, struct, col, substring, length, expr
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'gadget'),(2,'VR'),(2,'AR'),(3,'hi-fi')], schema = ['ID','Product'])

df = df.withColumn('Dummy',lit('Dummy'))

#While exploding later, the datatypes must be the same, so we have to cast ID as a String.
df = df.withColumn('ID',col('ID').cast('string'))

#Creating the list of distinct values.
df = df.groupby("Dummy").agg(*exprs)
df.show(truncate=False)
+-----+---------------+-----------------------+
|Dummy|collect_set(ID)|collect_set(Product)   |
+-----+---------------+-----------------------+
|Dummy|[3, 1, 2]      |[AR, VR, hi-fi, gadget]|
+-----+---------------+-----------------------+

def to_transpose(df, by):

    # Filter dtypes and split into column names and type description
    cols, dtypes = zip(*((c, t) for (c, t) in df.dtypes if c not in by))
    # Spark SQL supports only homogeneous columns
    assert len(set(dtypes)) == 1, "All columns have to be of the same type"

    # Create and explode an array of (column_name, column_value) structs
    kvs = explode(array([
      struct(lit(c).alias("key"), col(c).alias("val")) for c in cols
    ])).alias("kvs")

    return df.select(by + [kvs]).select(by + ["kvs.key", "kvs.val"])

df = to_transpose(df, ['Dummy']).drop('Dummy')
df.show()
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 key|                 val|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|     collect_set(ID)|           [3, 1, 2]|
|collect_set(Product)|[AR, VR, hi-fi, g...|
+--------------------+--------------------+

df = df.withColumn('val', explode(col('val')))
df = df.withColumnRenamed('key', 'Column').withColumnRenamed('val', 'Value')
df = df.withColumn('Column', expr("substring(Column,13,length(Column)-13)"))
df.show()
+-------+------+
| Column| Value|
+-------+------+
|     ID|     3|
|     ID|     1|
|     ID|     2|
|Product|    AR|
|Product|    VR|
|Product| hi-fi|
|Product|gadget|
+-------+------+
```

**Note:** All the columns which are not strings, should be converted into String like `df = df.withColumn('ID',col('ID').cast('string'))`. Otherwise, you will get error.

Comment: thank you! To make it generic - is it possible to apply `collect_set` within a loop (on all cols in the DataFrame) as there are > 2 cols in my example.

Comment: I have generalized it now.